# C Tag does not get prompted while adding Tags

Tags: bug, status-completed

While editing a question for retagging I noticed that the c tag does not get prompted.

[image]

This seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch; that's indeed a bug. The "prioritize an exact match" logic was overlooked in the recent improvements. That's fixed now; thanks.

Comment: Wow! Such a fast fix on a live site?? I'm stunned!! No releases, no passing it to testers, no Q&A crap? Never seen anything like this. Good!

Comment: @TomasTelensky: Who's a better tester than the user who actually uses the site? Deploy early, deploy often, and [cherish a great community of people who care and who let you know when you screwed up](http://balpha.de/2011/06/a-shout-out-to-the-people-of-meta/) :)

Comment: @balpha: Yes it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The same for `r`! Moreover, when i write `r`, it shows me `c#`!

Comment: [tag:c#] has c-sharp as a synonym, which makes it the most-used tag that includes an "r". The actual [tag:r] tag now is the first match, though.